# Passing a sub array as an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

This is an easy one, I am sure, but I can't seem to find it on google.

If I have a function:

```
foo(int[] a) {}
```

and I want to call it with a subarray of an array:

```
for instance: myNums[3]+ (i.e. an array {4,5,6}), given myNums:
int[] myNums = { 1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Of course, I don't want to create a new array of just those sub items. I certainly could just pass the array and the index, but then I would have to write all the function code with offsets...ugly.

So, how does one do this in C# (.NET 2.0)?

`foo(&myNums[3])` is reporting unsafe.

`foo(myNums[3])` won't work (it is passing just an int).

Do I need to map this to some kind of collection?

Comment: If it were plain C, `foo(&(myNums[3]))` would have been indeed correct, FWIW.

Comment: If it were C, foo(myNums+3) will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a function exactly as defined (i.e. it takes an array), there's no way you can do this.

If you'd have a function that would take some collection interface instead, e.g.:

```
void foo(IList<int> a) { ... }
```

then you could pass an array to it, and you could also write your own `IList<T>` implementation that wraps a subrange of any other `IList<T>` (but there isn't a stock solution for this in FCL).

Comment: I think this: "but there isn't a stock solution for this" is what I am looking for. That is too bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Passing the address of an array to a function is something not supported by C# out-of-the-box. Either you have to do it using **unsafe** method, the code will be C-like (though you need to compile with unsafe option). or you would have to code it the way managed code are ought to be, in this case, pass the **offset**.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int[] a = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        unsafe
        {
            fixed (int* c = a)
            {
                SubArrayPointer(c + 3);
            }
        }
        SubArray(a, 3);
    }

    unsafe void SubArrayPointer(int* d)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Using pointer, outputs 7 --> {0}", *d));
    }

    void SubArray(int[] d, int offset)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Using offset, outputs 7 --> {0}", d[offset]));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ extension methods:

```
int[] myNums = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };

var subset = myNums.Skip(2).Take(2); //will contain 3,4

int[] subsetAsArray = myNums.Skip(2).Take(2).ToArray();
```

This assumes you are using .NET 3.0+. You'll also need to include System.Linq in your code file.

Comment: This creates a copy, and he is specifically asking for an alias.

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx (support for linq added as a reference that works in .net 2.0)